R markdown: Rotating header and footer page number to match landscape orientation of page
I am generating a report and have rotated pages with figures to landscape orientation for better visibility in the final PDF output. However, I do not know how to rotate the page number and headers to match. Is there a way to do this?
---
title: "MarkdownExample"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead[L]{Workplace}
  - \fancyhead[R]{Summary Report}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}  
  - \usepackage{float}       
  - \usepackage{graphicx}    
output:
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
      fig_caption: true
      toc: true
      extra_dependencies: ["float"]
include-before:
- '`\newpage{}`{=latex}'
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
    
---
---

## 1. Introduction

This report fulfills workplace requirements. Figures follow:

\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Users/figurepath.png}
\caption{Caption for Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
PDF output with header on top and page # on bottom
I tried this and got closer, but now the top right header is clipping behind the figure, and I cannot move the left header or page number to the correct spot.
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\fancypagestyle{landscape}{
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[L]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{90}{Workplace Longer Text for Example}}} 
    \fancyhead[R]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox{90}{Summary Report}}} 
    \fancyfoot[C]{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
  }
\thispagestyle{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Users/cburnham-SEA/Desktop/SFBAYRAILS_test/figures/fig12.png}
\caption{Caption for Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

Example:
Landscape page with portrait page header/footer locations, which are now rotated 90 degrees but remain in their original space
